# How to Create a jquery plugin which shows given number of boxes on page and highlight the box on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to Create a jquery plugin which shows given number of boxes on page and highlight the box on mouseover. 
When user clicks on the box, it removes the box from its place and shows it at the center of the page in bigger size.
If user clicks on the box again, it goes back to its original position.
Number of boxes to be displayed are configurable.

Comment: Post the code what you have tried..

Comment: i am bit confused to start as i have tried few examples in jsfiddle but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all the boxes a class with the same name, for example,

```
<div class='box'></div>
```

then, here's a starting point for your code. This will make the box fill the page when clicked, and will make the background colour of the box change to red when hovered over.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').click(function(){
        $(this).css({'position':'fixed','width':'400px','height':'300px'});
    });

    $('.box').hover(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','red');
    });

});
```